# httpruntime.cache on local machine and appfabric cache on servers

Tags: appfabric-cache, httpruntime.cache

Can any one help me develop an cache architecture where I can use httpruntime.cache when using localmachine (for development purposes) and use appfabric cache when application running on server?

I currently have the appfabric code already implemented. I know need to the logic to identify the localmachine usage and switch caching mechanism to httpruntime.cache...

Thanks to all gurus in advance...

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need the same common client interface for all tour cache providers : Get, Put, Remove, ... It' not difficult and you can take a look at [Service Stack Caching](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching).

An Ioc frameork like StructureMap or Unity will help you to use the appropriate provider based on a static or dynamic test.